# How to identify if a input value is changed in a set of array inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can i detect if an input value is changed.. i have a series of inputs which is from an ajax request.

something like this:

```
for each result of the ajax request
 print some <input type="text"> here
```

i tried to use an id to detect the changes made but multiple inputs have the same id and it seemed not to work on my case.

done something like this but it does not work, maybe because i have many input with the same id?

```
$('body').on('DOMAttrModified propertychange paste', '#rn', function() {
    alert("test");
});
```

Comment: Have you tried [onchange()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp)?

Comment: thank you so much holydragon.. it workedd!!! the next problem would be how to add a class on a specific input .. btw thank you so much.. i just changed the propertychange to change.. thankkssss

Comment: [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_add_class.asp) is how to add class.

Comment: thanks holydragon. how could i mark your comments as accepted? im new here. thanks

Comment: I will convert the comments here into a single answer so it will be official.

Comment: Don't get in the habit of having duplicate ids, it'll cripple your code eventually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [onchange()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) to detect any changes on the input. For example,

```
<input type="text" onchange="doSomethingOnChange()">
```

This will trigger `doSomethingOnChange()` every time the value in the input is changed.

Now that you want to add classes to html elements. [This](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_add_class.asp) will guide you on how to do such task.